# Force android app to relaunch completely if application loses focus

Tags: android

Is there a why to manipulate the `AndroidManifest.xml` (or any other way) so that when an app loses focus (during any activity), it has to completely reload the app (from the start), as opposed to just launch the `onResume`?

Cheers

Comment: Use some restart method in the onResume! :D

Comment: But i'd have to do that in every activity! Surely there's a manipulation so that it applies to all!?

Comment: @Jacob, you are saying there is no other way!? Schucks

Comment: Take a look at the  `activity` attribute `clearTaskOnLaunch` or maybe `finishOnTaskLaunch` Here is the whole list :: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element

Comment: Why would you want that? If you just wanna refresh some data or views, there are more convenient methods as restarting an app is significantly longer. If you think you must do this, afaik you cannot do that from the manifest. Easy way is to do that onResume of some BaseActivity which other activites of yours would extend.

Comment: @DeividasStrioga, At the launch, I check whether the user is still licenced to use the app. If they keep the app open, or never close it on their tablet, they could get around the licence (as it currently stands).

Comment: If all you want to do is check the license status of the user, then I would consider your idea of forcing the user to the root activity every time the app is reloaded to be a poor pattern.

Comment: @Barns, I'd have to agree with you there, I think I will consider alternative routes.

Comment: @dantan04 While it makes sense, licenses usually last weeks or months. During that time the app should get killed (unless user uses very few apps) or phone restarted. What I would do is either keep the license check at the app start or just check if user has license on activities onCreate. If the license is expired, send the user back to login/appropriate screen.

Comment: If you want to do that in all activities you must implemente the ActivityLifeCycleCallback in Application class!